# number of rows in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a web app in asp.net which contains crystal reports.I have a drop down list which contains the number of records to be displayed.
so if the user selects 5 the report showld show 5 records per page,if he selects 10 ot should show 10 records per page..
can you help me guys..i am not able to fine any solution for it

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Number parameter named PageSize.
2. Add the following to the Detail section's "New Page After" conditional formula:

   ```
   Remainder(RecordNumber, {?PageSize})=0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Paginate the resultset and keep on updating the pagesize according to the value in dropdown list

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/PaginationSorting.aspx